# How to display the sentiment analysis values in a pie chart using matplotlib in python 3.6?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, nlp, sentiment-analysis, textblob

The main objective is to display the sentiment analysis values positive, negative and neutral of any user input in a pie chart. While, the code has no error, the pie chart only displays the neutral value as 100% of the entire chart and classifies the input as neutral even after a negative or positive is fed in as the input.

I have tried modifying the conditional statements and taking passing the main input variable itself in Textblob. However, the expected results have not been generated.

```
from textblob import TextBlob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def percentage(part,whole):
    return 100*float(part)/float(whole)


inp = input("Enter something:")

positive = 0
negative = 0
neutral = 0
polarity = 0


for word in inp:
    analyzer = TextBlob(word)
    polarity += analyzer.sentiment.polarity
    if analyzer.sentiment.polarity > 0:
    positive += 1
    elif analyzer.sentiment.polarity < 0:
    negative += 1
    elif analyzer.sentiment.polarity == 0:
    neutral += 1

positive = percentage(positive,(positive + negative + neutral))
negative = percentage(negative,(positive + negative + neutral))
neutral = percentage(neutral,(positive + negative + neutral))

positive = format(positive,'.2f')
negative = format(negative,'.2f')
neutral = format(neutral,'.2f')

if (polarity > 0):
    print("Positive")
elif (polarity < 0):
    print("Negative")
elif (polarity == 0):
    print("Neutral")

labels = ['Positive ['+str(positive)+'%]', 'Negative ['+str(negative)+'%]', 
'Neutral ['+str(neutral)+'%]']
sizes = [positive, negative, neutral]
colors = ['blue','red','yellow']
patches, texts = plt.pie(sizes, colors=colors, startangle=90)
plt.legend(patches,labels,loc="best")
plt.title("Polarity Pie Chart")
plt.axis('equal')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The Expected output is to correctly classify and display the positive, negative and neutral in the pie chart. But the output, regardless of the input's context, only classifies as neutral and pie chart also only displays neutral.

Comment: If you print `sizes`, does it ever contain any non-zero value for "positive" or "negative"? If not, what does this have to do with matplotlib?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I have used matplotlib for generating the pie chart w.r.t to the percentage composition. Regarding non-zero values for positive and negative, could you a little more specific? I have incremented their values and also tried using different variables for the percentage. No improvements.

Comment: Is this a matplotlib problem or a textblob problem? Find out by `print(sizes)` and judging on whether this is what you expect.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest tried that as well. It just prints the formulated positive, negative and neutral values where positive and negative are not being computed.

Comment: So it's unrelated to plotting. I suspect that textblob considers single characters as neutral. Maybe you want to rather have it compute the sentiments of whole words?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Hi! I have resolved the problem that I was facing. Apparently the problem was in Textblob as it was not increasing the count of positive and negative. So, I used a different method to do so. I would like to thank you for your inputs and support

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is with for loop, it is taking each letter into the loop rather than a word.

Use inp = inp.split(" ") before for loop, we will get the desired pie chart.

Answer (score 0):

`positive = format(positive,'.2f') ....` This statement converts the number into string,
..so when you compare with `" if (polarity > 0) --> print("Positive")"` it compares as a string..

Redo as `" positive = float(format(positive, '.2f'))`